# Editing the logo link destination in joomla (yootheme warp 7)

Tags: html, css, joomla

I'm trying to edit the default logo link destination in joomla (using yootheme's warp 7).

Currently it links to the default homepage, whereas I'd like it to link elsewhere.

I can edit the logo's CSS just fine, and I can also access the module that contains the logo.

However, the link seems to be wrapped around the module itself.

```
<a class="tm-logo" href="mysite.html">

<div class="mysite-logo">
    <img alt="My Website" src="/mysite/images/yootheme/demo/default/logo.svg"></img>
</div>
```

If I could edit the html directly, that would be awesome, but that doesn't seem to be an option. And when I try to give the image a link via the module manager, things break pretty hard.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated

Comment: Perhaps it's possible to change the link's destination with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

Go to your template manager -> customize template -> edit theme.php

search for "tm-logo", and change the href of that line to whatever link you like.